# Set equality, regarding indices.

Tags: real-analysis

This is a true analysis question, not set-theoritc.

I was reading a set equality regarding

$\{ a : f(a) \geq \epsilon \text{ for some } \epsilon > 0 \} = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ a: f(a) \geq 1/n\}$

This seems really obvious, but I can't give ea full justification. I am thinking this is due to Archimedean property. Please do not write a set-therotic proof because I am sure the answer is purely analysis and something obvious.

Comment: Did you establish one of the two inclusions?

Comment: I'm not sure what counts as "not set-theoretic", but the key is that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n\geq 1$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @carmichael561, ah so *it is* Archimedean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the LHS is contained in the RHS by the Archimedean Property. Indeed, given any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon} \iff \epsilon > \frac{1}{n}$ so that $f(a) \geq \epsilon \implies f(a) \geq \frac{1}{n}$.

The RHS is contained in the LHS because if $f(a) \geq \frac{1}{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, then we can just take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$, since it is certainly positive.

Comment: So my suspicions were correct, good to know.